# Aggregate two value when a condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle

Edit: I need to partition by ID and Month

I have the table below:

```
TableA1     50       low    201803   20
```

I would like to multiple `hoursxWorkingDaysInMonth` when `Cat = 'low'`.

ID    Hours    Cat    Month    WorkingDaysInMonth

I have the SQL below, but it doesn't account for the condition

```
SELECT SUM(HOURS * MONTH) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, MONTH) AS TESTING,
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Sample results and more detailed data would help.  It is entirely unclear why you are using an analytic function.

Comment: I have updaed my question as I need to partition by ID and Month. I was hoping I could use a window function for this?

Comment: what result u want to achieve and why are u using partition ?

Comment: I want the logic on each row and only should multiple by each unique ID and Month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT SUM(A.HOURS * A.WORKINGDAYSINMONTH) AS AMT
FROM TABLEA A
WHERE cat = 'low';
```

If you want the logic on each row:

```
select a.*,
       (case when a.cat = 'low' then a.hour * a.workingdaysinmonth end) as amt
from tablea a;
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I need to partition by ID and Month

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cat = 'low' THEN HOURS * WORKINGDAYSINMONTH END AS AMT
FROM TABLEA

SELECT DECODE(CAT,'low',HOURS * WORKINGDAYSINMONTH END) AS AMT
FROM TABLEA
```

You can use a CASE or DECODE statement to do this work.

In case if you want to add a default to the rest of the rows you can have else statement in your query like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cat = 'low' THEN HOURS * WORKINGDAYSINMONTH 
ELSE 0 END AS AMT
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: IF `cat` is not `low`, then `null` will be printed in the `amt` column

Comment: I have updaed my question as I need to partition by ID and Month. I was hoping I could use a window function for this?